# Setting field on struct gets lost?

Tags: go

```
type Project struct {
    ID   int    `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

type Commit struct {
    ID            string `json:"id"`
    Message       string `json:"message"`
    CommitterName string `json:"committer_name"`
    CommittedDate string `json:"committed_date"`
    Project       Project
}

func (c *Commit) SetProject(project Project) {
    c.Project = project
}
```

```
var commits []Commit // pre-populated list of commits

// goroutine 1
for _, commit := range commits {
  fmt.Println(project) // this prints out with the expected result
  commit.SetProject(project)
  fmt.Println(commit) // this prints out with the expected result
}
ch <- commits

// goroutine 2
for commits := range ch {
  fmt.Println(commits[0].Project) // => {0 }, project is not there
}
```

How can I set the project on the commits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, it looks like `commits` is of type `[]Commit`. If that's the case, the `commit` in the for loop is a copy of the array element, and changing that will change the copy, not the Commit in the array. So, use indexed access and modify the commit in the array:

```
for i, _ := range commits {
    commits[i].SetProject(project)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a type which requires a pointer receiver, it's better to always handle values of that type via a pointer to prevent unexpected copies. Even if you were to call the method directly on the value in the slice via the index, you're going to always have the chance that the values need to be used elsewhere in your code requiring you to ensure that you're mutating the correct value.

In this case, it's advisable to use a slice of of pointers for `commits` to avoid the issue altogether:

```
var commits []*Commit
```